# How to use itertools combinations and permutations to find this?

Tags: python

I have an iterable, say:

```
a = [0, 1, 2, 3]
```

I want all possible collections of cardinality 3, such that:

- Repetition is allowed up to a constraint of repeating no more than 2.
- Order matters.

The first condition is a generalization of **with replacement** property that allows arbitrary number of repetitions of any element.

What I tried:

`itertools.permutation` doesn't allow repetitions.

`itertools.product(a, repeat=3)` allows repeating an element once twice and thrice which violates first condition.
If I put repeat=2 it gives subsets of length 2, I want 3.

How do I do that?

Comment: PS: I do realize there's no straightforward way, or built-in function. Just want a smart answer that make use of available function. One-liners are preferred, if possible.

Comment: What is fixed in all versions of your problem? In other words, do you only want collections of cardinality 3, so no generalization of that is needed? What about the size of the iterable and the number of repetitions? Will a routine that generates too many collections then filters them acceptable, or do you require one that only generates what is desired?

Comment: The problem is as stated in the outset. Sorry for confusion. I have a list, I want all possible combinations such that: the combination has length of 3, elements are allowed to be repeated by only twice, no more. Order matter.

Comment: when you say order matters...just for clarification, does that mean `(1, 1, 0)` is invalid? Or do you simply mean you need all permutations, such that both `(1, 1, 0)` and `(0, 1, 1)` are valid?

Comment: (1, 1, 0) is perfectly valid. Cause an element is repeated twice only. This has nothing to do with me saying 'order matter'. 'Order matter' means (1, 1, 0) is different from (0, 1 ,1). Thanks.

Comment: `list(set(permutations(a*repetition, cardinality))`?

Comment: @Darkonaut I like one-liners ! that's so smart. I don't think the solution can be reduced any more

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a quick and dirty. (Or well, not all that dirty i suppose) Handle the repetitions yourself before passing to permutations. Take a set to ensure uniques.

```
from itertools import permutations
n_repeats = 2
cardinality = 3
a = [0, 1, 2, 3]

for group in set(permutations(a*n_repeats, cardinality)):
    print(group)
```

Output snippet:

```
(3, 0, 2)
(0, 1, 1)
(1, 0, 3)
(1, 3, 2)
(3, 0, 3)
(0, 1, 2)
(1, 0, 0)
...
```

Comment: That is genius, sheer genius. Reason: it is the fastest among the solutions provided. With this, I don't create extra elements then bother filtering them as others suggested.

Comment: But, why did you put set() ?? it should be list(). Ahhh, got it, some elements will have (0, 0, 0) and (0, 0, 0) repeated again, because they are thought of as different orderings.

Comment: yep, you got it :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think itertools is going to give you this kind of granular control out of the box. You'll either need to write your own algorithm or take some output from itertools and filter what you want -- for example:

```
from itertools import product
a = [0, 1, 2, 3]
cardinality = 4
repeats = 2
[c for c in product(a, repeat=cardinality) if len(set(c)) > cardinality - repeats]
```

**Output**

```
[(0, 0, 1, 2),
 (0, 0, 1, 3),
 (0, 0, 2, 1),
 (0, 0, 2, 3),
 (0, 0, 3, 1),
 (0, 0, 3, 2),
 (0, 1, 0, 2),
 (0, 1, 0, 3),
 (0, 1, 1, 2),
 (0, 1, 1, 3),
 (0, 1, 2, 0),
 (0, 1, 2, 1),
 (0, 1, 2, 2),
 (0, 1, 2, 3),
 (0, 1, 3, 0),
 (0, 1, 3, 1),

 ...

 (3, 2, 3, 1),
 (3, 3, 0, 1),
 (3, 3, 0, 2),
 (3, 3, 1, 0),
 (3, 3, 1, 2),
 (3, 3, 2, 0),
 (3, 3, 2, 1)]
```

Comment: Order doesn't matter in your solution. But it sounds promising.

Comment: I mean (0, 0, 1) is different from (0, 1, 0) which is not included in your solution.

Comment: I see @AlexDeft. Agreed, this would probably be better with `product` and `repeat = 3` instead of `combinations_with_replacement`

Comment: Perfect! but I have a question, why did you put len(set()) > 1
Can you make a general solution for any maximum number of repetitions allowed and any cardinality required?

Answer (score 1):

You can use your `product` approach but with the index so that you can keep track of how many times an index is repeated in the product. If it's more than 2 (maximum repetitions allowed), you omit that product:

```
from itertools import product
from collections import Counter

max_repetitions = 2
a = [0, 1, 2, 3]

res = []
for p in product(enumerate(a), repeat=3):
    index_counts = Counter((i for i, _ in p))
    if not index_counts.most_common(1)[0][1] > max_repetitions:
        res.append([e for _, e in p])

print(res)
```

**Output**

```
[[0, 0, 1],
 [0, 0, 2],
 [0, 0, 3],
 [0, 1, 0],
 [0, 1, 1],
 [0, 1, 2],
 [0, 1, 3],
 [0, 2, 0],
 [0, 2, 1],
 [0, 2, 2],
 [0, 2, 3],
 [0, 3, 0],
 [0, 3, 1],
 [0, 3, 2],
 [0, 3, 3],
 [1, 0, 0],
 [1, 0, 1],
 [1, 0, 2],
 [1, 0, 3],
 [1, 1, 0],
 [1, 1, 2],
 [1, 1, 3],
 [1, 2, 0],
 [1, 2, 1],
 [1, 2, 2],
 [1, 2, 3],
 [1, 3, 0],
 [1, 3, 1],
 [1, 3, 2],
 [1, 3, 3],
 [2, 0, 0],
 [2, 0, 1],
 [2, 0, 2],
 [2, 0, 3],
 [2, 1, 0],
 [2, 1, 1],
 [2, 1, 2],
 [2, 1, 3],
 [2, 2, 0],
 [2, 2, 1],
 [2, 2, 3],
 [2, 3, 0],
 [2, 3, 1],
 [2, 3, 2],
 [2, 3, 3],
 [3, 0, 0],
 [3, 0, 1],
 [3, 0, 2],
 [3, 0, 3],
 [3, 1, 0],
 [3, 1, 1],
 [3, 1, 2],
 [3, 1, 3],
 [3, 2, 0],
 [3, 2, 1],
 [3, 2, 2],
 [3, 2, 3],
 [3, 3, 0],
 [3, 3, 1],
 [3, 3, 2]]
```

Comment: Got, so produce elements with maximum number of repetitions, then, filter them out. Actually a neater way of knowing how many elements got repeated is asking for len(set(~) ) and subtract it off from the fixed size. The difference will show if something is repeated more than allowed. It can be compressed to one liner.

Comment: @AlexDeft True but that assumes `a` has unique elements.

Answer (score 0):

How about using set `difference` or subtraction from `itertools.product`:

```
cardinality = 3

set(itertools.product(a, repeat=cardinality )).difference(set((x,)*cardinality  for x in a))
```

or

```
set(itertools.product(a, repeat=cardinality )) - set((x,)*cardinality  for x in a)


Out[2024]:
{(0, 0, 1),
 (0, 0, 2),
 (0, 0, 3),
 (0, 1, 0),
 (0, 1, 1),
 (0, 1, 2),
 (0, 1, 3),
 (0, 2, 0),
 (0, 2, 1),
 (0, 2, 2),
 (0, 2, 3),
 (0, 3, 0),
 (0, 3, 1),
 (0, 3, 2),
 (0, 3, 3),
 (1, 0, 0),
 (1, 0, 1),
 (1, 0, 2),
 (1, 0, 3),
 (1, 1, 0),
 (1, 1, 2),
 (1, 1, 3),
 (1, 2, 0),
 (1, 2, 1),
 (1, 2, 2),
 (1, 2, 3),
 (1, 3, 0),
 (1, 3, 1),
 (1, 3, 2),
 (1, 3, 3),
 (2, 0, 0),
 (2, 0, 1),
 (2, 0, 2),
 (2, 0, 3),
 (2, 1, 0),
 (2, 1, 1),
 (2, 1, 2),
 (2, 1, 3),
 (2, 2, 0),
 (2, 2, 1),
 (2, 2, 3),
 (2, 3, 0),
 (2, 3, 1),
 (2, 3, 2),
 (2, 3, 3),
 (3, 0, 0),
 (3, 0, 1),
 (3, 0, 2),
 (3, 0, 3),
 (3, 1, 0),
 (3, 1, 1),
 (3, 1, 2),
 (3, 1, 3),
 (3, 2, 0),
 (3, 2, 1),
 (3, 2, 2),
 (3, 2, 3),
 (3, 3, 0),
 (3, 3, 1),
 (3, 3, 2)}
```